# Replacing blank number cells in Excel using Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am iterating through an Excel spreadsheet to obtain values using Java.
 Whenever I encounter a blank String cell I am able to replace this blank cell with null. 
However, when trying to do the same with number value cells I am not able to do so. 
Below is an example of my code.

```
            case 3:
                    String name;
                    if ("".equals(cell.getStringCellValue())) {
                        userType = "null";
                    } else {
                        userType = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    }
               break;

            case 4:
                    int hits;
                    hits = (int) cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    if(Integer.valueOf(hits) == 0) {
                        hits = 1;
                    }
```

Can anyone advise me on what I need to do to detect that the cell is blank and replace this value with the number 1?

Comment: The value `"null"` is not the same as `null`. It's actually a string with the letters `n`, `u`, `l` and `l`. I assume `userType` is a `String`? You could define `hits` as an `Integer` instead of `int` and you'll be able to use `null`, but not `"null"`.

Comment: **Sorry, I have no idea of Java** I'm here because the Excel tag, but in Excel, other way of detecting empty (blank) cells would be checking the Lenght of the cell's value. If it's 0 it means there is nothing there. Hope this can help a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if equals to `" "` and then assign 1.
You can also try to parse to int and catch if `notANumberException` and then assign 1.

What you are doing right now is getting int value while it might not even be an int and then check if 0 but `"null" != null != 0`